# Save pipeline output to a variable

Tags: bash

I have two .jar file in a pipeline. 1.jar will output two lines, both of which will be the input of 2.jar. 
Now I want to store the each line of the intermediate output of 1.jar to variables A and B, while allowing 2.jar to take both lines as input.

```
java -jar 1.jar | XXX | java -jar 2.jar
```

As a detour, I could do

```
java -jar 1.jar | tee out | java -jar 2.jar
```

and read the file to save the variables, but I'd like a more straight-forward way of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final version, with refinements by Jonathan Leffler:

```
IFS=$'\n' a=($(java -jar 1.jar)); printf "%s\n" "${a[@]}" | java -jar 2.jar
echo ${a[0]}   # line 1
echo ${a[1]}   # line 2
```

Comment: You probably need `echo "$a"` so that the newline is preserved.  Consider: `a=($(java -jar 1.jar)); printf "%s\n" "${a[@]}" | java -jar 2.jar`.  This gives you the two lines in two separate array elements.  I was working around to an array based solution, but hadn't got there yet.

Comment: Don't downplay your contribution; I was playing stupid games with `3>&1` etc (and failing, I might add), but you simplified the process by capturing the output and then feeding it.  All I did was help a little with refining that important idea!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Cool Team effort then.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. From my side `${a[@]}` seems to store each token instead of each line. Instead of "token11 token12 token13\ntoken21 token22\n", `"%s\n" "${a[@]}"` is printing "token11\ntoken12\ntoken13\ntoken21\ntoken22\n"

Comment: @user2684206 Good point! (I tested it with a single word per line so I didn't notice that.) I believe that setting the internal field separator to newline will solve the problem. Check out the edit above.